# Adding nav links on either(both) sides of an image

Tags: html, css

Having a lot of trouble with this, I think i'm almost there. This is what it looks like so far however its now uneven (the image logo is more to the right and not in the center anymore. I'm trying to get it so that the image is in the center and 2 links on either side of it. [Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwK7R.png)

HTML:

Current code:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>The Collective</li>
    <img src="images/jc.jpg">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Store</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Sorry I'm fairly new to all of this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: wrap your img tag inside li

Comment: so I done this  <li><img src="images/jc.jpg"></li> instead it slightly shifted it more to the left but the image is still slightly more to the right then dead center?

Comment: is your logo properly trimmed? you should post a  [JS Fiddle Demo](https://www.jsfiddle.net) . That would be lot helpful.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ap9puLpn It appears to look fine on here but when actually executed with my logo the logo is slighly more positioned on the right making it uneven? Logo is properly trimmed :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#container{
 background-color:white;
 width: 1250px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 
 
}

#header{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 width: 1250px;
 height:200px;
 
}

body {
 background-color:#EEE;
}

#navbar li {
 
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 40px;
}

#content {
 padding: 10px; 
}

#main1 {
 width: 400px;
 float:left;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:2px;
 padding:10px;
 margin-left:150px;
  
 
 
}
#main2 {
 width:400px;
 float: right;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:2px;
 padding:10px;
 margin-right:150px;
}

#footer {
 clear:both;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title> JC4ME Homepage </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
  
  <div id="header">
   <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>The Collective</li>
     <li><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/xc68nnswf/image.jpg"></li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Store</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
   <div id="main1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

   </div>
   <div id="main2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="footer">
   Copyright &copy; 2016 Ibz 
  </div>
 </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Put image inside `<li>` tag

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>The Collective</li>
    <li><img src="images/jc.jpg"></li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Store</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It moved the image slighly more left which is good but it is still not dead center still slightly more situated to the right.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ap9puLpn/ It appears to look fine on here but when actually executed with my logo the logo is slighly more positioned on the right making it uneven?

Comment: Why don't you add logo here, so we can see actual problem?

Comment: How would I add it? Sorry v new to stackoverflow and web development in general, is there a way to add it via fiddle or would you like me to include it in the question?

Comment: Upload your logo to some image uploading service for example [postimage](http://postimage.org/), then link it.

Comment: Your image is not properly trimmed, if you see [http://s33.postimg.org/xc68nnswf/image.jpg](http://s33.postimg.org/xc68nnswf/image.jpg). Circle is not on center. It is aligned right. Crop it properly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean when you said circle is not on center and aligned right, looks fine to me? Sorry if i'm becoming nuisance, I am very greatful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something with `display:table`:

```css
#navbar {
    display: table;
}
#navbar ul, #navbar img {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navbar .left, #navbar .right {
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#navbar li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Collective</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=LOGO">
    <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `li` element an `inline-block` with `vertical-align:bottom` and your center `ul`

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>The Collective</li>
        <li><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Store</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```